How to prevent update() in GetX from being called during widget building in Flutter?
I am using Flutter with the GetX package for state management. I encountered an issue where calling the update() method from GetX during widget building results in the following error:
Unhandled Exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
To prevent this error, I modified the GetX package file get_controllers.dart to defer the update() call using WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback. Here’s the code snippet I added:
void update([List<Object>? ids, bool condition = true]) {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (!condition) {
      return;
    }
    if (ids == null) {
      refresh();
    } else {
      for (final id in ids) {
        refreshGroup(id);
      }
    }
  });
}

While this approach seems to work, I understand that modifying the package directly is not recommended for maintainability reasons. I want to achieve the same goal without modifying the GetX package directly. I am also unsure if my current approach is a good or bad practice.

You don't have to modify GetX code
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    update();
  });


I have also used this approach earlier, but I wanted to avoid wrapping each update() call to prevent rewriting the same code multiple times.

is every time you calling update() will cause exception? then i think you should find out why and fix it@UsamaBaig
